# Moving Maximum in last 5 minutes in R

Tags: r, time, max, min

I was wondering how to implement a moving maximum and minimum for a price in the last 5 minutes in O(n) time in R. My data consists of two columns: one with the time of day in seconds and the other with price. Right now, I take the current time, subtract 5 minutes, subset for the last 5 minutes, and then search for min and max at each index, so the operation is O(n^2). Is there any way to do this in O(n)?

Sample data:

time
[34200.19, 34200.23, 34201.45, ..., 35800, 35800.2, 35800.5]

price
[100, 103, 102, ..., 95, 97, 99]

Comment: It's technically not O(n^2) but O(n) if the average number of events in the last 5 minutes is constant.

Comment: Well at each index, I'm performing an O(n) search for the maximum and minimum, so for the whole data set, wouldn't that be O(n^2)?

Comment: The search for the maximum is only O(1). You could say O(5)...

Comment: Oh my sample data is misleading, there are many transactions per minute, I just didn't want to make it overly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The following compares a direct approach with a slightly more efficient varient, but it looks to scale as about n^1.6 on the values I've tried it with (10,000 - 100,000) - partly depends if incresing n is assumed to be more points in the same time period, or extending over a longer period.

```
#Create some data 
n <- 10000
d <- data.frame(t=as.POSIXct(24*3600*runif(n), origin = "2014-01-01"),x=runif(n))
d <- d[order(d$t),]

d$inmax2 <-d$inmax <- rep(FALSE,n)
d$inmax2[1] <-d$inmax[1] <- TRUE

if (max(diff(d$t)) > 300) warning("There are gaps of more than 300 secs")

#Method 1, assume that you've done something like this
t1 <- system.time({
  for (i in 2:n) d$inmax[i] <- !any((difftime(d$t[i], d$t[1:(i-1)] ,units="secs") < 300) & (d$x[i] < d$x[1:(i-1)] ))
})

#Method 2    
t2 <- system.time({
cand <- 1
next_cand <- 2

while (next_cand <= n)
{
  cand <- cand[difftime(d$t[next_cand],d$t[cand],units="secs")<300]
  cand <- c(cand[d$x[cand] > d$x[next_cand]],next_cand)
  if(length(cand)==1) d$inmax2[cand] <- TRUE
  next_cand <- next_cand + 1

}

})

rbind(method1=t1,method2=t2)
#         user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child
# method1     14.98     0.03   15.04         NA        NA
# method2      2.59     0.05    2.63         NA        NA
all(d[[3]]==d[[4]])
# TRUE
```

The approach is to run through keeping all possible candidates in the past 5 minutes that are not less than the present one. If there are no such candidates the current must be the maximum. I assume that you can generalise to minimum.

Possibly doesn't work if you want to know maximum in last 5 minutes between datapoints rather than at datapoints though - not sure if you require that

Answer (score 0):

Sort the dataframe by time first. Then maintain a max heap of the price, removing the lost price entries after every shift. Since rebalancing a heap is `O(log n)`, this will be `O(n log n)`. For implementing a max heap, consult any algorithms textbook (although I may edit this post later with one).

Comment: Thanks! I knew it could be done in O(n log n) time, but I also read that it could be done in O(n) time with two stacks representing a queue. Do you know if there's an implementation of that in R?